# LFS object not found

Tags: git, clone, atlassian-sourcetree, git-lfs

I was going to clone a project, which the capacity is over 18GB, on Sourcetree from my repository, but It's not working properly and makes an error about GIT-LFS.

Actually, Cloning the repo worked well when I tried it several times before, but It haven't been working after I did something that I didn't know.

Here's a log from Sourcetree When cloning.

```html
git-lfs/2.2.1 (GitHub; windows 386; go 1.8.3; git 621d1f82)
git version 2.14.1.windows.1

$ git-lfs.exe filter-process
Error downloading object: SVN/The game/PSDS/Characters/Brother/BrotherRight/BrotherRight07.png (3769b03): Smudge error: Error downloading SVN/The game/PSDS/Characters/Brother/BrotherRight/BrotherRight07.png (3769b034529a54d533b0f8658b1effafef66c9855b38a337040ba953b98c8513): [3769b034529a54d533b0f8658b1effafef66c9855b38a337040ba953b98c8513] LFS object not found: [404] LFS object not found

[404] LFS object not found
github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/errors.newWrappedError
 C:/Users/ttaylorr/go/src/github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/src/github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/errors/types.go:170: [3769b034529a54d533b0f8658b1effafef66c9855b38a337040ba953b98c8513] LFS object not found
github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/errors.newWrappedError
 C:/Users/ttaylorr/go/src/github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/src/github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/errors/types.go:170: Error downloading SVN/The game/PSDS/Characters/Brother/BrotherRight/BrotherRight07.png (3769b034529a54d533b0f8658b1effafef66c9855b38a337040ba953b98c8513)
github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/errors.newWrappedError
 C:/Users/ttaylorr/go/src/github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/src/github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/errors/types.go:170: Smudge error

ENV:
LocalWorkingDir=F:\The game
LocalGitDir=F:\The game\.git
LocalGitStorageDir=F:\The game\.git
LocalMediaDir=F:\The game\.git\lfs\objects
LocalReferenceDir=
TempDir=F:\The game\.git\lfs\tmp
ConcurrentTransfers=3
TusTransfers=false
BasicTransfersOnly=false
SkipDownloadErrors=false
FetchRecentAlways=false
FetchRecentRefsDays=7
FetchRecentCommitsDays=0
FetchRecentRefsIncludeRemotes=true
PruneOffsetDays=3
PruneVerifyRemoteAlways=false
PruneRemoteName=origin
AccessDownload=basic
AccessUpload=basic
DownloadTransfers=basic
UploadTransfers=basic
GIT_CONFIG_PARAMETERS='filter.lfs.smudge=' 'filter.lfs.required=false' 'color.branch=false' 'color.diff=false' 'color.status=false' 'diff.mnemonicprefix=false' 'core.quotepath=false'
GIT_DIR=.git
GIT_LFS_PATH=C:\Program Files\Git LFS
GIT_PAGER=cat
```

I need help REALLY..