# I want to get rid of the batch or the not found object from the old `git` LFS repository before pushing

Tags: git, gitlab, git-lfs

I want to get rid of the batch or the not found object from the old `git` LFS repository that I deleted. Here is the result:

```
git push
warning: redirecting to https://gitlab.com/ooh/biography-images.git/
batch response: Repository or object not found: https://gitlab.com/ooh/trip-to-buenos-aires.git/objects/batch                                                                                                                        
Check that it exists and that you have proper access to it
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://gitlab.com/ooh/biography-images'
```

The folder `biography-images` is a submodule of the `biography` submodule of the `personal-blog` repository.

The folder `trip-to-buenos-aires` is not a submodule of all these submodules and this repository.

The `personal-blog` and `trip-to-buenos-aires` repositories are in the same folder called `ooh` that does not have a `.git` folder.

The `trip-to-buenos-aires` repository used to have LFS, but I renamed it to `trip-to-buenos-aires-old`, and I created a new repository `trip-to-buenos-aires` without LFS.

Almost all these repositories and submodules have the same `main` name.

I followed these following quesstions:

- [Error when getting git LFS files: Object does not exist on the server: [404] Object does not exist on the server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62852772/error-when-getting-git-lfs-files-object-does-not-exist-on-the-server-404-obj)
- [Git LFS "Object does not exist on the server" because it's trying to find old file not tracked by LFS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69081045/git-lfs-object-does-not-exist-on-the-server-because-its-trying-to-find-old-fi)
- [Git LFS cannot find object for new repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72380548/git-lfs-cannot-find-object-for-new-repo)
- [LFS upload missing object but the file is there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52612880/lfs-upload-missing-object-but-the-file-is-there)
- [Git lfs (missing) object, on push, even if it shouldn't be](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70923109/git-lfs-missing-object-on-push-even-if-it-shouldnt-be)
- ["This LFS object could not be found."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76768884/this-lfs-object-could-not-be-found)
- [LFS object not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46985972/lfs-object-not-found)
- [Git LFS files not found on server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35049603/git-lfs-files-not-found-on-server)
- [GitLab and LFS Pushing with Missing Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64975707/gitlab-and-lfs-pushing-with-missing-files)
- [Uploading LFS objects - Repository or object not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64473233/uploading-lfs-objects-repository-or-object-not-found)

But these questions did not solve my problem. The same error persisted.